# Read file to one string and separate it in perl

Tags: string, perl, file

So I have file which looks like:

```
Name, Surname, Number
Name2, Surname2, Number2
Name3, Surname3, Number3
```

I want to read it all to one string in Perl, and I want it to look like:

```
"Name, Surname, Number, Name2, Surname2, Number2, Name3, Surname3, Number3"
```

But I really don't have idea how to do it :/ I'm new in Perl. I know only, that to open file I need to do:

```
open($list, "<", $file)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $list = do {
    use autodie;
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    chomp(my @lines = <$fh>);
    join ', ', @lines;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the lines from a filehandle into an array, then joining that array into a string.

```
open (my $list, "<", $file) or die;
my @lns = <$list>;
chomp @lns;
my $string = join(",", @lns);

print "$string\n";
```

Comment: `Can't modify <HANDLE> in chomp at - line 3, near "<$list>;"` :-P

Comment: Also, don't forget to check the `open` call for failure.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will work.  Since you're new to Perl like me, a different but perhaps more beginner-friendly (straightforward, IMO) way of doing it would be:

```
use strict;

sub main(){

my $output; 
    open( 'sourcefile', "<$ARGV[0]" )
          or die("Error: cannot open file '$ARGV[0]'\n");

    while (my $line = <sourcefile>){
        chomp $line; #will remove the newline for you.
        $output = $output . $line;
    }
    print $output;
}

main();
```